# How to restrict one exposed filter per content area?

Tags: 8, theming

On my Drupal 8 site a have a /search view page that contains two exposed filters. I would like to expose them in different areas, for example to use search bar in the navigation, and filter by content type in the "content" block. But if I pick in 'advanced' tab 'Exposed form in block' "Yes", then both my filters appear in the navigation bar.

How can I split my exposed filters into different areas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a module that seems to do exactly that: [MEFIBS - More exposed forms in blocks](https://www.drupal.org/project/mefibs).

Apart from that you could follow a workaround mentioned on that module project page where you clone your Views Display, don't change the Path, only change the Exposed settings. You will end up with two different blocks that can be placed in different regions, but working on the same Views page.

Comment: by "clone your display" you mean "dublicate view" or "dublicate page"? Can not find the option clone the view display in interace

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's `Duplicate` instead of `Clone` in D8. One View can have more than one Display. Display types can be `Page`, `Block`, etc. So in your case you can Duplicate the Page.